# Created / Modified date doesn't change if I copy and overwrite a destination file in windows

Tags: windows, svn

I just found a strange condition in Windows 8. Why doesn't a file update its modified/created date if it was copied and overwritten to ?

Even I deleted the file in a folder first, then copied a new file with the same file name into the folder, the properties detail in the file still showed previous created/modified date. I think it's a common problem that most users would feel confused.

I ask the question since I want to monitor whether there is any image was copied and overwritten in a folder. So if I can't rely on created/modified date in the file, how does a version control system like SVN detect an image file was modified.

Comment: Windows deliberately retains the creation date from the old file, because many applications update files by deleting and rewriting them and updating a file shouldn't change the creation date.  This should not, however, affect the modification date.

Comment: I found a [discussion](http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/76541-date-created-doesn-t-change-after-copy-paste.html) might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable last modification field in explorer. What your are seeing is simply "Date" and not "Last modification date"